# how to run redis-cli commands with Chef?

Tags: redis, chef-infra

Here is how I do it today (snippet of code in my recipe):

```
execute "redis-cli-command" do
  command "echo 'MY COMMAND' | redis-cli"
  user "root"
  action :run
end
```

but somehow this does satisfy me completely, I wonder if there is a better/nicer way.

Comment: You can do 'redis-cli COMMAND' instead

Comment: Yes I know that. I guess I may have not formulated the question properly... and I suppose there isn't a better way.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "set k v" | redis-cli --pipe
```